# Best practice: [[maybe_unused]] or anonymous argument?

Tags: c++, c++17, c++14

Let's say I have a class with a virtual function with one argument and two different implementations of this virtual function. The first implementation uses the argument while the second does not. The second case will produce a compilation warning. There are two ways I can think of to suppress the warning.

1. Using an anonymous parameter.
2. Using the `[[maybe_unused]]` annotation.

What is considered "best practice" between the two?

Thank you in advance for your answers.

Comment: If the parameter is not used, I omit the parameter name.  If the parameter *may* be used (because something like `#ifdef __APPLE__` and uses it only on that platform), I'll tag it with `[[maybe_unused]]`.

Comment: If it seems useful for readability to have the name of the variable, it is quite common to keep it as a comment: `void f(type /*name*/);`

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The most authoritative source we have for "best practice" in C++ is the [C++ Core Guidelines](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines). And on the topic of [unused arguments](https://isocpp.github.io/CppCoreGuidelines/CppCoreGuidelines#Rf-unused), they have this to say

> ## F.9: Unused parameters should be unnamed
>
> ...
>
> If parameters are conditionally unused, declare them with the `[[maybe_unused]]` attribute.

So the C++ Core Guidelines recommend leaving the parameter unnamed if it's never used at all. `[[maybe_unused]]`, by this rule, should only be applied if the parameter is unused in some situations, such as inside an `#ifdef` or (more modern) inside an `if constexpr`.